# calculation of increment value in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I want to pass the parameter value in style for calculate my width. my code is

```
function getValue(value) {
  if (value === 12) {
    return {
      width: '( 20 - value )%',
    };
  }
  return false;
}
```

but the width does not working. I am new to react. please help.

Comment: I'm confused? You just want to get (20 - value)%?

Comment: yes @JermahlWhite

Comment: so if the value is 12 what do you want the function to return? because otherwise it will return false

Comment: If it only returns when it's 12, you can just return {width:0.08} whenever it's 12 instead of (20 - value)/100

Answer (score 2):

You can't calculate if it's a string. Quote marks (`''`) make it a string. Also, `%` is a remainder operator. It gets the remainder of two numbers. It's similar to division. You can read more about the remainder operator on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())
I don't understand what this has to do with react, this is more just vanilla javascript.

I think what you may want is

```
function getValue(value) {
  if (value !== 12) { return false; }
  return {
    width: (20 - value)/100,
  };
}
```

You could also do the following since it only returns if the value if 12

```
var getValue = value => value === 12 ? { width: 0.08 } : false
```

This solution uses arrow functions, auto return, and ternary operators. You can read about them on mdn

Comment: free vote from me :) thanks for calling out remainder and also linking to MDN!

Comment: I feel violated. Edited without my knowing

Comment: Haha! I helped didn't I? :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell How did you help??? I need to know how you helps so I can express gratitude

Comment: Did you see what i edited and the comment i put? To view my edit you have to click the link `edited 1 hour ago`

Answer (score 2):

You need something like below. You are checking a constant value, so no need to do the arithmetic, just return 8. You can simplify the function as like below

```
function getValue(value) {
  // return object for style or undefined for no styling
  return value === 12 ? {'width': '8% !important' } : undefined;
}
```

If you were to keep the arithmetic because you wanted to just always do a calculation (for instance). Then a nicer way to write out the function would be like this.

```
function getValue(value) {
  return { 'width': `${20 - value}% !important` };
}
```

Comment: Why even use a second line? You could just check to see if it's 12, and if it is, return 0.08? since (20-12)% is always 8%

Comment: Agree with you :)

Comment: Free upvote because you agree with me and also because of quality. Definitely mostly because quality ;)

Comment: Free upvote and edits from me :) nice way to "think twice" ;) about the attempt!

Comment: I wrote your code..but when i use `width: '7%'`  it shows different width  and when i write `width: `${20 - value}%` `  it shows different width ..i don't know what is the difference between this two codes. and here value is 13    @JohnRuddell

Answer (score 1):

Try this

width: (20 - value) + ‘%’